# V brake tension adjusted by bending a wire

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, cable, terminology

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKEmi.jpg)I have v brakes with a stiff wire which you bend to adjust the release tension, as opposed to turning a screw. I love this system, it's such an instinctive way to adjust the tension. Anyone know what this system is called as the brake units are getting rusty (it's an old bike) and I'd like to replace them?

Comment: I've never found V brakes that have such a system. They all have a spring under each arm for pull-back.  Can you add a photo of your brakes showing the feature?

Comment: I've never seen such a scheme.  I'm guessing that your bike didn't originally use such a scheme, but it has been MacGyvered by a previous owner.  The bent wire will not provide reliable braking.

Comment: Have added a photo

Answer (score 4):

All but the cheapest V brake arms come with a spring tension adjustment screw. These screws push on the short end of the spring, but the springs are common to any V brake.

Models with adjustment screws still have the long arm of the spring alongside the caliper arm, it is still exposed and you can still bend it to make adjustments. So you could make do with your preferred method and take your pick of any quality brake you can find.

Turning the adjustment screw is a better way to do it, but there's nothing to stop you bending the spring on your own bike to achieve the same result.

Comment: Having used both the screw kind and the rod (I added a picture above), I find the rod a million times better. If any knowledgeable person can tell me where I can obtain them or what they are called, I'd be most grateful. Thanks!